# how to use action=remove in property mediator using wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I know how to set property using property mediator but don't know how to use remove property using property mediator. Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Generic+Properties

Sample : `<property name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>`